How to dynamically control iframe size from within a React app using postMessage API?
I have an embeddable React app that is embedded in a host website via an iframe. I need to adjust the iframe's height and width based on user interactions within the React app. I'm using the postMessage API for communication between the iframe and the host website.
Here is the relevant code:
host.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        #sample-iframe {
            border: none;
            height: 720px;
            width: 375px;
            max-width: 375px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            #sample-iframe {
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
                max-width: 100vw;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe
        allowfullscreen
        allow="geolocation"
        sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-presentation allow-top-navigation"
        src='javascript: window.frameElement.getAttribute("srcdoc");'
        srcdoc='
        <script>
            // Wait for the DOM content to be fully loaded
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                // Define a flag to track if the event has been triggered
                var eventTriggered = false;

                // Define the message handler function
                window.onmessage = function (event) {
                    // Check if the event has already been triggered
                    if (!eventTriggered) {
                        // Log the event
                        console.log("post event", event);

                        // Post the message back
                        event.source.postMessage(
                            {
                                iframeId: event.data,
                                scrollHeight:
                                    document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height ||
                                    document.body.scrollHeight,
                            },
                            event.origin
                        );

                        // Set the flag to true to indicate the event has been triggered
                        eventTriggered = true;
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>

        <body>
            <div id="book">Loading Widget...</div>
            <script>
                (function (w, d, s, o, f, js, fjs) {
                    w["Automicle-v1"] = o;
                    w[o] =
                        w[o] ||
                        function () {
                            (w[o].q = w[o].q || []).push(arguments);
                        };
                    (js = d.createElement(s)), (fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]);
                    js.id = o;
                    js.src = f;
                    js.async = 1;
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                })(window, document, "script", "w1", "./widget.js");
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                    const widgetId = params.get("widgetId");
                    const env = params.get("env");
                    w1("init", {
                        TARGET_ELEMENT_ID: "book",
                        WIDGET_ID: "some-widget-id",
                        ENVIRONMENT: "DEVELOPMENT",
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        '
        width="375"
        height="720"
        id="sample-iframe"
        title="widget"
    ></iframe>
</body>
</html>

React component code
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleMessage = (event) => {
            console.log("Message received from host:", event.data);
            if (event.data.iframeId) {
                window.removeEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
        };
    }, []);

    const adjustIframeSize = () => {
        const iframe = document.getElementById('sample-iframe');
        const newHeight = /* Calculate new height based on your logic */;
        const newWidth = /* Calculate new width based on your logic */;
        window.parent.postMessage(
            {
                iframeId: iframe.id,
                newHeight,
                newWidth,
            },
            '*'
        );
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={adjustIframeSize}>Resize Iframe</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;

What could be causing the iframe resize functionality to not work as expected, and how can I fix it? Idea is to I have a widget written in reactjs which is embedded in a website using iframe. Now, I want to alter the height and width of the iframe from a button click happening in the reactjs widget. Any suggestions or improvements to my current implementation are welcome.

A couple of things.
There is no code in your host page to receive a message from the iframe.
The sandbox setting doesn’t allow JS in the iframe.
Also I’m not sure why you need all the code in srcdoc. Why not just load the iframe via src?

I would also suggest looking at https://iframe-resizer.com as another approach to this.
